# Can you create a route 53 A Record that maps directly to the IP address of a ecs service and ecs task defined using the AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Can you create a route 53 A Record that maps directly to the IP address of a ecs service and ecs task defined using the AWS CDK?

I have the following code

```
FargateTaskDefinition taskDef = new FargateTaskDefinition(this, "DevStackTaskDef", new FargateTaskDefinitionProps()
{
    MemoryLimitMiB = 2048,
    Cpu = 512
});

var service = new FargateService(this, "DevStackFargateService", new FargateServiceProps()
{
    ServiceName = "DevStackFargateService",
    TaskDefinition = taskDef,
    Cluster = cluster,
    DesiredCount = 1,
    SecurityGroup = securityGroup,
    AssignPublicIp = true,
    VpcSubnets = new SubnetSelection()
    {
        SubnetType = SubnetType.PUBLIC
    }
});

new ARecord(this, "AliasRecord", new ARecordProps()
{
    Zone = zone,
    Target = RecordTarget.FromIpAddresses() //here is the line in question.
});
```

The ARecordProps.Target value is the one I'm stuck on. I can not find a way to get the ip address of the task that will be created. Does any one know if this is possible to do? I would really like to avoid using load balancers as this is a dev/test environment. I have also looked at the aws-route53-targets module and see that it only supports

- ApiGateway
- ApiGatewayDomain
- BucketWebsiteTarget
- ClassicLoadBalancerTarget
- CloudFrontTarget
- LoadBalancerTarget

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: No way to do it directly, but, you can do it with ECS Service Discovery https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html

Comment: Do you know if the limitation is in cloud formation or the CDK?